# How to deal with thrown errors in async code with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

The following test causes Jasmine (2.3.4, run in browser via Karma) to crash and not run any subsequent tests

```
it('should report as failure and continue testing', function (done) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    throw new SyntaxError('some error');
    done();
  }, 1000);
});
```

How can I have this test correctly report itself as a failure and carry on with subsequent tests?

Comment: I've posted a Q&A that may address your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006944/how-to-expect-an-asynchronously-thrown-exception-in-jasmine-angular2-typescr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocking the clock will give you the expected result.
Mocking the clock in general is a best practice for testing timeouts.

```
describe('foo', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        timerCallback = jasmine.createSpy("timerCallback");
        jasmine.clock().install();
    });
    afterEach(function () {
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });
    it('should report as failure and continue testing', function (done) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            throw new SyntaxError('some error');
            done();
        }, 1000);
        jasmine.clock().tick(1001);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there an approach that works for async code not useing timeouts? I just used a timeout here to simplify the example, what I'm actually doing are some integration tests that are waiting for things on the network

Comment: It's fine to use timeouts. Another solution for writing async code is using promises, checkout this great article - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/.

Comment: Sorry, I meant is there an approach for having tests not crash out when using async code. The actual code I am trying to test uses promises and an error in one of the then blocks is what's causing my tests to crash

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example? Do you have a catch() block in the end of the promise chain?