# How to expect an asynchronously thrown exception in Jasmine / Angular2 / Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, exception, asynchronous, jasmine

Given an Angular2/Typescript method that returns **nothing** and implements a .subscribe() handler which might throw, such as this:

```
onSubmit() { // returns nothing
  this.service.someCall(this.someData).subscribe(
    data => {
      return Promise.reject('This is an asynchronously thrown error.');
    },
    err => {},
  );
}
```

(For the moment, let's assume that there's a good reason for this .subscribe() handler to (probably conditionally) reject without other testable side-effects, thus resulting only in an error message bubbling up to the top of the application.)

How would one go about testing that this method resulted in a rejected Promise?

I found some people with the same question, but no elegant answers:

[How to deal with thrown errors in async code with Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252888/how-to-deal-with-thrown-errors-in-async-code-with-jasmine#)

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/529

https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/7769526

Comment: It's hard to know exactly how to make a good answer here. It may be a case were the difficulty in writing good tests indicates a refactor of the code is in order. For example, why is an observable throwing with a rejected promise rather than just throwing an error which you would catch in `err=>{}`. And what should `onSubmit` do in this case. The answer to that last question is what you should test. And who is returning the Promise, the code in the call back or the observable. Why isn't this handled anywhere in onSubmit?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by stubbing the console.error() method (in this case, I am using Sinon):

```
it('should throw exception from component on submit', (done) => {
  // Jasmine isn't capable of capturing an exception thrown from an *asynchronous* operation.
  // However, that error eventually finds its way to console.error(), so we can stub
  // that method and wait for it to be called.
  sandbox.stub(console, 'error').callsFake((...err) => {
    expect(err[1]).toEqual('This is an asynchronously thrown error.');
    done();
  });
  component.onSubmit();
});
```

Are there any other/better ways to go about this?

Comment: You need to be careful that you aren't testing your testing framework. When I run this, I get a console error from mocha about an unhandled promise, which is not what I want to test. If `onSubmit` should log an error, there should be code in the function to do that.